# SQL-Developer: cant open the program

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used SQL Developer to import big csv files, but today I can't open the program.. When I doubleclick on the .exe this window appears but the progress bar stops at this point, like in the img, and then the window get closed without an error..
Anybody know what could be wrong??

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you should be contacting your desktop administrators... they're much more likely to be able to solve any issues you have.

Comment: do you know if there is a log-file or something similar to see whats wrong??

Comment: did you try opening your file from inside of SQL Developer?

Comment: I can't open SQL Developer, so theres no chance for me to open a file inside of SQL Developer..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I asked Jeff Smith and he gave me the answer:
You have to go to the Application Data directory, Roaming Profiles, SQL Developer folder. Find the subfolder with the SQL Developer version number you’re using in the directory name, and try renaming or deleting it.

In my case it was: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.0.2.15.21

[Jeff Smith's Website](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the solution. You just made the internet a smarter place :)

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug. The problem exists where you don't save your password on the connection, then open a file/object and leave it open on close. When the application goes to open again, it tries to restore those documents/editors and gets 'stuck' b/c it can't find the password on the connection. I'll log that and try to get fixed in our next release.

Comment: If you follow ZerOne's answer be aware all you saved connections and other settings will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue on stratup would appear to be centre around the proxy settings for your SQL Developer installation. Setting the proxy to use 'No Proxy' seems to override the username and password prompt at startup.

To configure this follow Tools > Preferences > Web Browser and Proxy > Proxy Settings and select the No proxy radio.

When you restart you should no longer be asked for a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both of the solutions (ZerOne's solution of renaming or deleting the "SQL developer" folder and paulrcove's changing no proxy settings), but neither worked after rebooting my computer. As a workaround I renamed the "SQL developer" sub folder to a previous version of SQL Developer (from system4.0.2.15.21 to system4.0.2.15.20). Note that I've never installed the previous version. When I start up SQL Developer I am asked if I want to import the settings from the "previous version", and all of my old settings get imported with the exception of saved passwords in connections. It is probably a system setting that has acquired a conflict, as SQL Developer had been working fine for weeks before this feature appeared, and it is present even if I upgrade to the latest version of SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced similar situation. But the **SQL Developer** logo instead of getting closed, it hung in my case. I followed below 2 steps to get SQL Developer running.

1. First I ended the **SQL Developer** task by going to **Task Manager** in
   Windows.(It might be 'kill' command in case of Linux OS)
2. I selected **Start** -> **Programs**. Then I did right click on '**SQL Developer**' and chose '**Run as administrator**'.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem, when I had renamed my folder "sqldeveloper" with sqldeveloper.exe and other required files to another name. So, maybe you should check the folder's name.